# Used flex box to align at start everything is fine but it can't be centered

Tags: html, css

The code is running fine . The problem I am facing is of alignment .
I searched for many question in **SO** but in vain.

**I want to center align the `deviceCardFlex` in below snippet with bottom card align to the left .**
As cards can be in any number so applying property for last card only is not feasible.

I want to align the `deviceCardFlex` in the `center` of the body (It solve my problem but when there are extra cards like only 1 left at bottom it also align in `center`).

When I try to use `flex-start` (It solve my bottom card problem like 1 card is left at bottom will align to `left` but the whole container `deviceCardFlex` is not `center` aligned) .
I tried to use `margins` but they need to be change on every change in `screen size` . I know `@media` is for that purpose only but can it be possible without that.

I tried `space-arround` , `space-between` so that in between space can be maintained between cards but the problem persists with bottom card

```css
/*.deviceCardFlex1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}*/

.deviceCardFlex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-left: auto;
  padding-right: auto;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.deviceCard {
  position: relative;
  /* float: left; */
  width: 300px;
  height: fit-content;
  margin: 2% 2%;
  padding: 0 1% 1%;
  border: 2px solid rgb(126, 126, 126);
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<!--<div class="deviceCardFlex1">-->
  <div class="deviceCardFlex">
    <div class="deviceCard">
      <h3 class="deviceCardHead">Lenova Yoga Laptop Pro</h3>
      <ul class="deviceCardData">
        <li>Windows 11</li>
        <li> 8GB Ram</li>
        <li>1TB SSD</li>
        <li>Intel Core i7 (11th Gen)</li>
        <li>NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050</li>
        <li>15.6 inch Full HD Display</li>
        <li> Dolby Audio</li>
        <li>1 Year Onsite Warranty</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="deviceCard">
      <h3 class="deviceCardHead">Lenova Yoga Laptop Pro</h3>
      <ul class="deviceCardData">
        <li>Windows 11</li>
        <li> 8GB Ram</li>
        <li>1TB SSD</li>
        <li>Intel Core i7 (11th Gen)</li>
        <li>NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050</li>
        <li>15.6 inch Full HD Display</li>
        <li> Dolby Audio</li>
        <li>1 Year Onsite Warranty</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="deviceCard">
      <h3 class="deviceCardHead">Lenova Yoga Laptop Pro</h3>
      <ul class="deviceCardData">
        <li>Windows 11</li>
        <li> 8GB Ram</li>
        <li>1TB SSD</li>
        <li>Intel Core i7 (11th Gen)</li>
        <li>NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050</li>
        <li>15.6 inch Full HD Display</li>
        <li> Dolby Audio</li>
        <li>1 Year Onsite Warranty</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="deviceCard">
      <h3 class="deviceCardHead">Lenova Yoga Laptop Pro</h3>
      <ul class="deviceCardData">
        <li>Windows 11</li>
        <li> 8GB Ram</li>
        <li>1TB SSD</li>
        <li>Intel Core i7 (11th Gen)</li>
        <li>NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050</li>
        <li>15.6 inch Full HD Display</li>
        <li> Dolby Audio</li>
        <li>1 Year Onsite Warranty</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="deviceCard">
      <h3 class="deviceCardHead">Lenova Yoga Laptop Pro</h3>
      <ul class="deviceCardData">
        <li>Windows 11</li>
        <li> 8GB Ram</li>
        <li>1TB SSD</li>
        <li>Intel Core i7 (11th Gen)</li>
        <li>NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050</li>
        <li>15.6 inch Full HD Display</li>
        <li> Dolby Audio</li>
        <li>1 Year Onsite Warranty</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="deviceCard">
      <h3 class="deviceCardHead">Lenova Yoga Laptop Pro</h3>
      <ul class="deviceCardData">
        <li>Windows 11</li>
        <li> 8GB Ram</li>
        <li>1TB SSD</li>
        <li>Intel Core i7 (11th Gen)</li>
        <li>NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050</li>
        <li>15.6 inch Full HD Display</li>
        <li> Dolby Audio</li>
        <li>1 Year Onsite Warranty</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="deviceCard">
      <h3 class="deviceCardHead">Lenova Yoga Laptop Pro</h3>
      <ul class="deviceCardData">
        <li>Windows 11</li>
        <li> 8GB Ram</li>
        <li>1TB SSD</li>
        <li>Intel Core i7 (11th Gen)</li>
        <li>NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050</li>
        <li>15.6 inch Full HD Display</li>
        <li> Dolby Audio</li>
        <li>1 Year Onsite Warranty</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
<!--</div>-->
```

Comment: So you want to align the cards themselves "deviceCard"? or the their parent "deviceCardFlex"? asking because u wrote these exact 2 lines >> I want to center align the cards in below snippet // I want to align the deviceCardFlex in the center of the body

Comment: I want to center align the `deviceCardFlex`

Comment: with  the bottom card aligned to the left

Comment: Centering only horizontally of a block-level element (your div.deviceCardFlex): please try setting a width (like `width: 500px;`) and margin like this `margin: 0 auto:`

Comment: Additionally `position: relative` or `float: left` have no effect (i think) , because div.deviceCard is a flex item

Comment: `position: relative` is for other tags and `float` is commented

Comment: @ckoala it is not centering with `width: 500px` and margin like this `margin: 0 auto`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DeviceCardflex** box takes the whole body width already, you can check that by giving it a background color.

What really concerns you is giving the children boxes the appropriate width ratio of the parent width so they be aligned in center by using the **`flex`** property.

Just try to update your style with the following code

```
.deviceCard {
    position: relative;
    /* float: left; */
    width: 300px;
    height: fit-content;
    margin: 2% 2%;
    padding: 0 1% 1%;
    border: 2px solid rgb(126, 126, 126);
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    transition: 0.3s;
    flex: 0 0 21%;
}
/*.deviceCardFlex1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}*/

.deviceCardFlex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-left: auto;
  padding-right: auto;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.deviceCard {
  position: relative;
  /* float: left; */
  width: 300px;
  height: fit-content;
  margin: 2% 2%;
  padding: 0 1% 1%;
  border: 2px solid rgb(126, 126, 126);
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  transition: 0.3s;
  flex: 0 0 21%;
}

@media (max-width: 776px){
  .deviceCard {
    flex: 0 0 48%;
    margin: 2% 1%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 500px){
  .deviceCard {
    flex: 0 0 90%;
    margin: 2% auto;
  }
}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: It solve the problem . I see that with `width` also it can be solved . Can you tell about `flex` property you used at last

Comment: Thanks ,also can it be possible to solve the problem without changing the `width` or `flex`

Comment: Glad to help. 
**flex** Property concerns about three factors and the are in order grow and shrink and basis of the childe box inside the flex container so we change the last factor which is flex basis to give our design the appropriate layout you can git it more by following [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex). 
Wish you the best!

Comment: Can it be possible to solve problem without changing `width` or `flex` property . Know that `@media` is for that purpose only . But can it be possible

Comment: Answer is updated with media queries too, and there is no way else flex property factors can solve such a problem of the flexbox style, you can't control start flext content justifying and make the children boxes width to auto filling the box at the same time.

Comment: If answer solved your question, then you better choose the answer and close the question thankfully

Answer (score 1):

So, since you want the element "deviceCardFlex" to center align on both x/y axis, and that element's parent is the body it self. You can either write the following css to the body itself or to a parent wrapped around deviceCardFlex

```
Parentof_deviceCardFlex {
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and the commented code in question snippet but it is not working

Comment: Please show more HTML / CSS of deviceCardFlex's parent element

Comment: @ckoala the "Parentof_deviceCardFlex" is just a placeholder name for whatever element he was gonna decide to become the parent of "deviceCardFlex" be it the body it self or another element wrapped around the "deviceCardFlex" element as i mentioned.

Comment: @Ahmed I'm sorry, my comment was supposed to be directed at Rana. I appreciate your answer!

Comment: @ckoala it is directly in body containing cards only

Comment: @Rana Forgot to mention it, but you need to give a width and height to deviceCardFlex. That way the parent given flex can assign a fixed space at left and right of its child in this case "deviceCardFlex".

Comment: @AhmedEssam not working with that also . You can see by copying the complete snippet and applying changes . Not working with fixed `width` also

Answer (score 1):

Just simple

```css
.deviceCardFlex {
   ...
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: center;

}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer , yes it will solve problem a little bit as there will be lot white space left when all are in `column` with a single card in each line . I want all area covered with cards with a margin between them in center with bottom card in the left .